# will css bootstrap doesn't work when it is rendered as part of angular2 components?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have taken some free downloadable template which is built in bootstrap, CSS and Jquery.

If I try to render the html contents (with proper references for CSS,JS) the application/functionality works fine

The functionality i am referring here is expand/collapse feature of the left side menu bar written in css/jquery as part of the template.
But when I try to render the same html as a angular2 component (as angular2 HTML templateUrl) the above menu functionality is not working

any ideas what are the possible mistakes?

My component is as follows

```
@Component({
    selector: 'MenuLayout',
    templateUrl: './HTML/Layouts/Layout.html',
    providers: [ClientAPIService, Constants],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Layout.html file contains all the related HTML tags with CSS classed referred in it.

In Idex.html file, all the CSS are referred

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have replicated this issue and checked in the code to [Github url](https://github.com/snkrishnan1/Angular2AspNetCore)

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: How are you adding your css?

Comment: CSS are added as a reference in the index.html -   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at how your CSS encapsulation on your top level component is defined (it is where you would have your style declaration) ?

Example:

```
@Component({

  ...

  encapsulation:    ViewEncapsulation.None,

  styles:           [
    ...
  ]
})
```

More on https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-components/view_encapsulation.html

Comment: i tried suggested by you, still it doesn't work. anything else need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Put the full path to your assets. Like this:

```
 <link href="/fullPathToMyAssets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I have replicated this issue and checked in the code to Github url https://github.com/snkrishnan1/Angular2AspNetCore    Can you please tell me where is the problem?